# Grouping with Nulls T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, grouping

I have this problem with a SQL query (SQL Server 2008)

```
SELECT id, client, SUM(debt), date
FROM Table GROUP BY id, client, date
```

Returned from the query is

```
id client debt date
1  jim x  500  05/05/2012
2  jack a 900  06/06/2012
2  jack a 500  null
```

Is there a way to add in this scenario Jack a's debt (1400) and display the non null date i.e. 06/06/2012.

A person can only have 2 records max and 1 record is always date null so is there a way to do the sum and use the date that is not null?

Thanks

Comment: What if jack has multiple rows with different dates? Which date should be used then?

Comment: What if Jack A also has debt of 400 on 06/04/2012; which date does the `NULL` date record get included in?

Comment: Apologies, id for jack a should be the same. Looking to use that date that is not null, assume only 2 records can exist per person and 1 record date is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To group by client you have to remove `id` and `date` from your GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id) AS newest_id,    -- or MIN(id) if you prefer
    client,
    SUM(debt) AS total_debt,
    MAX(date) AS most_recent -- or MIN(date) if you prefer
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY client
```